# Unable to perform the on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

With reference to the following link http://jsfiddle.net/Xtreu/, I am trying to do same functionality with on click event <kbd>Delete My Data</kbd> button with out using any form. I tried in different ways but it does not happened. Can Any one help me how to do the same example with on `click` event?

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/echo/html/">
    <input type="hidden" name="html" value="&lt;p&gt;Your data has been deleted&lt/p&gt;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete My Data" />
</form>
<div id="confirmBox">
    <div class="message"></div>
    <span class="button yes">Yes</span>
    <span class="button no">No</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn) {
    var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
    confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
    confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function () {
        confirmBox.hide();
    });
    confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
    confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
    confirmBox.show();
}

$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = this;
        doConfirm("Are you sure?", function yes() {
            form.submit();
        }, function no() {
            // do nothing
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated your JSFiddle, it's without any form tag -> http://jsfiddle.net/Xtreu/445/
Maybe you have to specify what's going wrong or what's not working in your code, because you want a button without form, but in your example code there is a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code without using `form`

Try this example

```
<div id="msg" style="display:none">Your data has been deleted</div>
<input type="button" id="d_btn" value="Delete My Data" />
<div id="confirmBox">
    <div class="message"></div> <span class="button yes">Yes</span>
 <span class="button no">No</span>

</div>
```

script

```
function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn) {
    var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
    confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
    confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function () {
        confirmBox.hide();
    });
    confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
    confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
    confirmBox.show();
}

$(function () {
    $("#d_btn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        doConfirm("Are you sure?", function yes() {
            $('#d_btn').hide()
            $('#msg').show()
        }, function no() {
            // do nothing
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xtreu/446/)

Comment: The Dialog box is showing at background. If html page contains the content then on click of button the alert box is not visible. How can we pop it in foreground

Comment: @user3300593 z-index : 9999 to the dialog #confirmBox

Comment: add css style to  #confirmBox{ z-index : 9999}

Comment: Now Onclick of button I am able to see the Dialog. Is it possible that once the Dialog box opens the focus should only be in dialog #confirmBox not html page. Just like alert. i.e; Until user press yes or no he can't perform anything in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

try this

your HTML

```
<form method="post" action="/echo/html/" id="frm">
    <input type="hidden" name="html" value="&lt;p&gt;Your data has been deleted&lt/p&gt;" />
    <input type="button" id='btnSubmit'value="Delete My Data" />
</form>
<div id="confirmBox">
    <div class="message"></div>
    <span class="button yes">Yes</span>
    <span class="button no">No</span>
</div>
```

your js code:

```
function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn) {
    var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
    confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
    confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function () {
        confirmBox.hide();
    });
    confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
    confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
    confirmBox.show();
}

$(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = this;
        doConfirm("Are you sure?", function yes() {

            $('#frm').submit(); //Changed
        }, function no() {
            // do nothing
        });
    });
});
```

In your code the button type was submit so I changed it as normal button and I gave id to your form and submit button.